# One node of Memcached on AWS act differntly

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached

**Waht is the problem:**

we have couple of websites running on 2 servers on AWS. Recently we are experiencing fluctuation in response time for the requests. We also have two cache nodes on AWS elastic cache. the type of the cache is Memcached.

After lots of investigation I found out that cpu usage of one of the cache node is fluctuating, it goes up for 10 minutes and come down for 5 mins. the graph of cpu for that node goes up and down.

**What I have done so far :**

I delete and add two new nodes (same problem)

I tried different zone (same problem)

When I clear the cache everything is fine for about 40 minutes and then we experience the fluctuation.

One of the node is always stable and when I add the other node the other one shows the problem. Even if I have one node with 24,000 item inside is stable and then when I add another node the first one (with 24000 items) will remain stable but the new one shows same problem after 40 -50 mins.

this is our configuration in web.config for the cache:

```
    <enyim.com>
        <memcached>
          <servers>
            <add address="our address" port="our port number" />
          </servers>
          <socketPool maxPoolSize="100"/>
          <transcoder type="Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultTranscoder, Enyim.Caching" />
          <keyTransformer type="Enyim.Caching.Memcached.TigerHashKeyTransformer, Enyim.Caching" />
        </memcached>
 </enyim.com>
```

Comment: Have you checked logs? What do they indicate is happening during those time windows?

Comment: I have checked the aws statistics of that servers and compere the getcmd, setcmd, etc none of the stats are following the pattern of cpu or wise versa. But I can say at the time that cpu is high I am reading images from cache usually images between 200kB to 1 MG. but not more than than that.